# JqGrid Search returning only one of the matching records

Tags: jqgrid

I have two questions regarding built-in search feature of JqGrid.

1. How to get all the matching search records?
2. How to make the search a case insensitive search?

In the JqGrid I have enabled the client side search. But I am seeing only the first record matching the search criteria.

Comment: You should include the code which shows which type of searching you use (singe/advance searching, toolbar searching) and how you do it. At the correct usage the searching results show all matching rows. The parameter `ignoreCase:true` can be used for case insensitive local searching.

Comment: @Oleg: Sorry for the late reply. The first one was not a problem as the last record was getting hidden under the horizontal scroll bar. The second one was solved by using ignoreCase:true. Thanks one more time.

Comment: If you have solved the problem by having an answer to the question, you should post it as an answer and mark it accepted. Do not put "Solved" in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `@Oleg` reply the problem was solved.

Only one record shown was due to the horizontal scroll bar overlapping the last row. And when `ignoreCase:true` was added to the jqgrid the search done in the jqgrid is now case insensitive.